# Can't install certbot on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, certbot, amazon-ecs

I set up Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance via ECS (elastic container service).

It seems like by default it doesn't have that many packages installed.

When I'm trying to install `certbot` using the command:

```
sudo yum install certbot
```

I get errors like:

```
Error: Package: python2-six-1.9.0-0.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-six >= 1.9.0
           Available: python26-six-1.8.0-1.23.amzn1.noarch (amzn-main)
               python-six = 1.8.0-1.23.amzn1
Error: Package: python2-certbot-1.4.0-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python2-cryptography >= 1.2.3
Error: Package: python2-acme-1.4.0-2.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: pyOpenSSL >= 0.13.1
           Available: python26-pyOpenSSL-0.10-2.8.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               pyOpenSSL = 0.10-2.8.amzn1
Error: Package: certbot-1.4.0-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: python2-six-1.9.0-0.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-six >= 1.9.0
           Installing: python26-six-1.8.0-1.23.amzn1.noarch (amzn-main)
               python-six = 1.8.0-1.23.amzn1
```

And it's not installed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the EPEL repository with Amazon Linux 2, because it is not compatible with this Linux distribution. Packages from EPEL are not intended for Amazon Linux 2, and even if you somehow managed to install one, it probably would not work.

You will need to obtain certbot from another source, or use another Linux distribution.

Comment: Well, the AWS documentation says otherwise...
Amazon Linux

Amazon Linux 2:

Install the EPEL release package for RHEL 7 and enable the EPEL repository.
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
you can find it here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Comment: @BANJOSA Yes, I'm aware of that. It's irresponsible of them to promote a repo that doesn't actually work with their distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your answer, but then how could I use another distribution? Would you maybe update the answer with some instructions, so the others can know too? I'm at a loss here... Thank you!